# Data-Equalizer Foundation 5 not working

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation-5

I tried to use these `data-equalizer` on the foundation framework to be able to have the same height for each column and, from that, be able to center vertically a text in this column.

Here is the HTML:

```
    <div class="row" data-equalizer>
<div class="small-2 columns" data-equalizer-watch style="background: #ff0000;">   
    <span>Monday:</span>
</div>
<div class="small-5 columns" data-equalizer-watch>
    <label>Start Time
        <input type="text" class="time start ui-timepicker-input" autocomplete="off" alt="{{timestampStart}}">
    </label>
</div>
<div class="small-5 columns" data-equalizer-watch>
    <label>End Time
        <input type="text" class="time end ui-timepicker-input" autocomplete="off" alt="{{timestampEnd}}">
    </label>
</div>
```

I also created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p889dsfz/) in order that you can see what I meant --> I want that the red background of the "Monday" goes until the end of the row.

Thanks for help.

Comment: I don't see any pictures on the JSfiddle...?

Comment: Sorry of the monday, there is no picture...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working version here: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p889dsfz/2/)

Make sure you include the Foundation equalizer script and initialise Foundation on page load.

```
$(document).foundation();
```